# How does Go run on G-WAN?

Tags: go, g-wan

I read that [G-WAN supports Go](http://gwan.ch/en_timeline.html). As far as I know, Go can only produce statically linked executables. So how does Go work on G-WAN, through CGI/FastCGI? Or simply invoking the executable with the raw request on stdin?

I would love to be able to program Go and take advantage of G-WAN's performance.

Comment: my understanding of G-WAN's whole point is that it compiles programs on the fly. So you should upload go source files that contain calls to handlers defined at G-WAN's side that will (I suppose) be linked statically by G-WAN when compiled on-the-fly at server-side

Comment: Paolo, You are right - that's the way G-WAN works for other languages (C, C++, D, Java, C-Sharp, Objective-C...) but GO is a special case, see why in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GO has its own *runtime*, it uses *segmented stacks* and it introduced *goroutines*, so a C program cannot (easily) embed GO the way C++, C-Sharp, Java can be used from C. This would be possible to do but many pitfalls would have to be resolved.

Therefore, for GO G-WAN has used `CGI`, which works very well if you have many CPU Cores ([re-tested today](http://gwan.com/benchmark/babel.html) with a newer release of GO on 6-CPU Cores).

Other precautions have been taken to prevent a long GO servlet from preventing G-WAN from processing other requests while the GO reply is built but the rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Normal `CGI`? One process per request?

Comment: Yes, but for a big fat GO executable (a compiled hello.go weights 1.2 MiB due to its embedded runtime) the performance is not bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

GO will be supported on Version 3.10 Check this link.

[G-WAN Supported Language](http://gwan.ch/faq#language)

But 3.10 is not released yet. Check the Google Go section for the required libraries maybe you will have better idea on how it is supported.

Comment: v3.10 is not a public release, it's a *beta* like v3.9. Let's hope that we will have a public 3.11 later this month, many new things were added those last times.